# Howto: Escape $(var) in Azure DevOps YAML

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

```
variables:
  buildSelected: '1.0.0.1234'

steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "Build Selected $(buildSelected)"
      Write-Host "Escaped '$(buildSelected)'"
    displayName: "Escape variable"
```

I would like the value 1.0.0.1234 & '$(buildSelected)' to be printed instead of what it's printing now:

```
Build Selected 1.0.0.1234
Escaped '1.0.0.1234'
```

Comment: Did you get any error message in this process? If you add an extra cmd task to output the value of `BuildSelected`, what's the value looks like?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT No errors.  Just the value in the argument is assigned AS is. Clarified the question further

Comment: You may need some tests to check if the value of $(buildToDeploy) is successfully passed to the ps script. Try adding a write-host $newvalue in script and check if it's empty. In my test, `-newValue '$(buildToDeploy)'` can work well. So you don't need to use '$#36;(buildToDeploy)'.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT:  What I want is store the LITERAL string $(buildToDeploy) in the variable (in the variable group).  I don't want to store the value of $(buildToDeploy) which is what's happening now.

Comment: Can you share a minimal sample about your yaml file? I tried with your ps script but get one error `The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.` I guess maybe I miss something here.

Comment: @Lance Li-MSFT: Simplified the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry but I'm afraid Azure Devops doesn't provide the feature to escape a pipeline variable. If the variable is used in this format `$(var)`, it will always be replaced with its value when using `Write-Host` to output it.

As I know in Powershell syntax, only the ` can be used to escape variables. See:

```
Write-Host "Build Selected `$`(buildSelected)"
```

Its output : `Build Selected $(buildSelected)`

Not sure if it's what you need, but escaping pipeline variables with complete `$(var)` is not supported. Azure Devops will always replace it with its value if it matches the `$(var)` format.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but in bash and solved it by adding the invisible character named "ZERO WIDTH SPACE" between "$" and "(". This way I can print out "$(Build.SourceVersion)" without it being replaced with the actual value.

I copied the character from https://invisible-characters.com/

```
---
trigger: none

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "$​(Build.SourceVersion): $(Build.SourceVersion)"
    displayName: Test Pipeline Variable Escaping
```

[image: escape pipeline variable]

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that i needed to have $web as a param in the script, but powershell was trying to find a variable named "web" which didnt exist.
To escape it, it needs to be wrapped in single quotes -> '$web'.

This is so that it treats $web as a string instead of a variable.
This then gives you get an error because the "inlineScript" step value must be in single quotes. So to escape the single quote you add another single quote.
Then you end up with ''$web''.

```
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'xxxx'
      scriptType: 'ps'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: 'az storage blob upload-batch --destination ''$web'' --source ./  --connection-string  xxx'
```

You could also use the multi-line format for the inlineScript using |

```
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'xxxx'
      scriptType: 'ps'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        az storage blob upload-batch --destination '$web' --source ./  --connection-string  $args[0]
```